# In Ruby, does reject or select combined with each results in multiple iterations?

Tags: ruby

Suppose the code below

```
arr = [:a, :b, :c, :d]

# version 1
arr.reject{|e| e == :c}.each{ |e| handle(e)}

# version 2
arr.each{|e| handle(e) unless e == :c}
```

The question is will the 1st version result in 2 iterations of the array: first in reject then in each, or is ruby smart enough to optimize the code into something like version 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerator::Lazy`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerator/Lazy.html) to process it in one iteration:

```
arr.lazy.reject { |e| e == :c }.each { |e| handle(e) }
```

This will also change the order of invocation. The first element is being processed by each block, then the second element and so on:

```
arr.lazy.reject { |e|
  puts "filtering #{e}"; e == :c
}.each { |e|
  puts "handling #{e}"
}
```

Output:

```
filtering a
handling a
filtering b
handling b
filtering c  # <- c doesn't make it to the 2nd block
filtering d
handling d
```

The non-lazy approach passes all elements to the first block and the results to the second block:

```
arr.reject { |e|
  puts "filtering #{e}"; e == :c
}.each { |e|
  puts "handling #{e}"
}
```

Output:

```
filtering a
filtering b
filtering c
filtering d
handling a
handling b
handling d
```

Comment: This is very useful. Thank you for sharing that this.

Answer (score 2):

The first version **cannot** be optimized into the second version, because they do not return the same object.

Both will call `handle` with `:a`, `:b` and `:d`, but the first version returns:

```
[:a, :b, :d]
```

while the second version returns:

```
[:a, :b, :c, :d]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there will be two iterations. If you `reject` items then the second iteration will not be the same size though as it operates on the result of the `reject` call.

The first version is the same as:

```
cleaned = arr.reject{ |e| e == :c }
cleaned.each { |e| handle(e) }
```

which makes it more clear that it actually is two method calls.

Comment: 2 method calls doesn't necessarily mean two iterations, for example with `Enumerator`s

Answer (score 1):

I cannot tell for sure but I think the answer is in the [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-reject):

> ```
> reject {|item| block } → new_ary
> reject → Enumerator
> ```
>
> Returns a new array containing the items in self for which the given block is not true. The ordering of non-rejected elements is maintained.
>
> If no block is given, an [`Enumerator`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerator.html) is returned instead.

The documentation of [`#each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-each) looks similar.

The key phrase here is *"If no block is given, an [`Enumerator`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerator.html) is returned instead"*.

I plain English, if a block is given, `reject` iterates over the array and creates a new array (that contains only the non-rejected items) and returns it. The `each` method is invoked on the new array; it iterates the new array.

Technically, the initial array is not iterated twice; the `each` loop runs over the new array returned by `reject`.

Regarding the other half of the question, Ruby is smart enough to know it cannot predict what the programmer wants. That's why it provides the programmer a way to avoid the double iteration: it returns an [`Enumerator`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerator.html) when a block is not given.

The second version of code you posted in the question runs faster as it iterates the array only once.